# Cloudflare page rules wildcard cache bypass not working

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

I was having problems logging into Wordpress, which was giving me the error:

> "Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable
>   cookies to use WordPress"

unless I enter "development mode" on Cloudflare.

The [Cloudflare docs](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-fine-grained-feature-co/) suggest `*example.or/wp-admin*`, but this doesn't catch wp-login, so I'm getting the cookie problems.

So I'm trying `*example.org/wp-*in`, which I thought should match wp-**log**in and wp-**adm**in.

I put the rule at the top, too, as it is the most specific. The two rules further down are:

`example.org/events/*` - bypass cache. Seems to be working.

`example.org/*` cache everything, always on. Again, seems to work.

The only thing I can think is that you can't use a wildcard in the middle of something like I have, but I can't find any suggestion that this is the case in the docs, and I can't add two separate rules as I only get 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a case of missing something so obvious.

The rule I had was `https://example.com/wp-*in` but this would clearly not match `https://example.com/wp-admin/` or 
`https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php`

The correct rule is, of course, `https://example.com/wp-*in*/*` and this resolved our problem.

Comment: You should select this as the answer - and I believe you would only need
example.com/wp-*in* as the rule.

Comment: `https://example.com/wp-*in*/*` this does not match `https://example.com/wp-login.php`. Additionaly this would match everything that starts with `wp-` and have `in` somewhere in the URL which does not seem good practice.

Answer (score 1):

This **Solved** the problem for me.

Hi, this morning I had the very same issue when logging on.

> "Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable
>   cookies to use WordPress"

I also found that by logging into cloudflare and entering "development mode" resolved the issue. (Thank you for mentioning this in your original post, it helped me to figure out where to look next).

Now the **only** thing I changed yesterday with regards to cloudflare was to one of my **Page Rules** (main domain page rule).

The change I made to this section was to the setting for **Edge cache expire TTL** . Yesterday I had changed this from -*Respect All Existing Headers*- to -*4 Hours*-.

This morning I changed the "Edge cache expire TTL" setting back to -**Respect All Existing Headers**- and I can now log-in as normal. :)

I hope this helps you too.

F.Y.I. I use a 3 rule setup for cloudflare.

```
Rule#1 = *example.com/wp-admin* 
Rule#2 = *example.com/*preview=true* 
Rule#3 = *example.com/*
```

Basically Rule #1 and #2 bypass the cache for the backoffice and page previews. Rule #3 caches everything else on the website.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. Your method also works, but additionally, double check your rules if they look anything like mine. Because I had made such a simple and stupid error - see my answer for the solution.

Comment: Thanks @digitaltoast. I use a 3 rule setup for cloudflare. I've included an example of the rules I use which work well for me. Added to my original comment because I couldn't type an asterisk in this comment section.

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange. Have you opened a support ticket? We really wouldn't do anything that would trigger this:

""Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress""

Comment: Yes, we opened a ticket on Tuesday morning, but I have no idea what the timescale for free plans is, so I thought I'd chuck it out here too!

So, are you saying that *example.org/wp-*in SHOULD be bypassing cloudflare for both wp-login and wp-admin? But it's still showing the cloudflare headers. Hmmm....

Comment: Using PageRules to bypass caching, etc. doesn't mean that it would actually bypass our proxy, so you're still going to see CloudFlare in the headers.